# PayPal subscription reactivation billing date

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I could not find anything explaining how a PayPal subscription (or recurring payment) works when the payment is suspended and then reactivated.

Suppose I start through ExpressCheckout APIs a subscription: starts the 1st january and is 10 euros each month. Then I suspend the subscription the 15th of February (I got 10 euros for January and 10 euros for February).

Suppose I reactivate the subscription the 15th of May:

- will I start receiving the money from the 15th of May or the 1st of the following month?
- if I start receiving the payments the 15th of May, will I receive the next payments the 15th of each following month or the 1st?
- will I receive the money also for March and April?

and above all: is it me or PP docs are confusing? (be sincere ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the subscription is suspended then each billing date is "ignored" and deemed not to be collected. March and April's payment would not be collected.

Once reactivated we will billing the customer on their original billing date which is the 1st. So once activated on the 15th of May we'd still charge the customer on the 1st of June.

I hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I REALLY needed this answer! I've been looking for it for a while... is this described somewhere I missed? If so, please point me to the docs as I'll probably need more info in the future...

Comment: You're welcome! Our Express Checkout Advanced Integration guide has the majority of Express Checkout Recurring Billing details listed on the link below starting on page 43. It's a bit of a read but has a lot of useful information.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_advancedfeaturesguide.pdf

Comment: @PP_MTS_Matt is this information still valid?  Given a yearly subscription, pausing it for a month in the middle of the year will do nothing?

Comment: btw the link is broken now